# Oracle iSQL function issue

Tags: sql, oracle, function, isql

EDIT: i have changed my code now.

I have a problem with my function i get no errors when creating the function and i can run a basic version of the function i made with no problems but when i call the entire function i get blank rows.

this version works

```
SELECT   SUM(t.estimated_hours*c.hrly_charge_rate)
FROM     task t, task_history ta, task_type tt, charge_grade c
WHERE    t.task_id = ta.task_id
AND      tt.task_type_no = t.task_type_no
AND      c.grade_no = tt.grade_no
AND      ta.task_history_id = 1;
```

but this does not work the rows are just blank ???

```
SHOW ERRORS 

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION total_cost (tn task.task_id%TYPE) 
RETURN NUMBER IS

    cost_var   NUMBER;

BEGIN
    SELECT   SUM(t.estimated_hours*c.hrly_charge_rate)
    INTO     cost_var
    FROM     task t, task_history ta, task_type tt, charge_grade c
    WHERE    t.task_id = ta.task_id
    AND      tt.task_type_no = t.task_type_no
    AND      c.grade_no = tt.grade_no
    AND      t.task_type_no = tn
    AND      ta.task_history_id = 1;

    RETURN   cost_var;

END;
/

-- my call select statment 


SELECT  total_cost(t.task_id) AS task_cost
FROM    task t;
```

it runs with no errors but the rows are all blank ? 
Can any show me what i did wrong please.

here Is the Entity Relationship Diagram (ERD)
[image: ERD]
AND QUESTION
**/*
(b) to calculate and return the total cost using standard rates of a given task at the date of the estimate 
(ie before any further changes to estimated hours were made.
Code scripts, including SELECT statements to test each function + ‘screenshot’ of the output from each test statement. */**

Comment: Try to run the query that's inside your function. an hint: why `having`?

Comment: I assumed the having would only show the first task_history_id equal to 1 so that i only get the first task before any added hours where made which makes a new id so you can see previous hours. as i need the first estimate hours, then times that by  hourly_rate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using an `HAVING` to apply a simple `WHERE` condition. Same examples:

```
SQL> create table groupTable (id number, num number);

Table created.

SQL> select sum(num)
  2  from groupTable
  3  where id = 1;

  SUM(NUM)
----------


SQL> select sum(num)
  2  from groupTable
  3  having id = 1;
having id = 1
       *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression


SQL> select sum(num)
  2  from groupTable
  3  group by id
  4  having id = 1;

no rows selected

SQL> select sum(num)
  2  from groupTable
  3  group by id
  4  having sum(num) = 1;

no rows selected

SQL> select sum(num)
  2  from groupTable
  3  where sum(num) = 1
  4  group by id;
where sum(num) = 1
      *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here


SQL>
```